# What would happen if one plugged a USB flash drive into a phone charger?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, charging

If someone were to insert a typical USB flash drive into a USB-A smartphone charger, what would happen to the flash drive?
Furthermore, what would happen if a wireless adapter or other non-storage USB device was inserted into a charger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely nothing *bad* would happen if **any** standard USB device were plugged into a USB charger.

At worst any "power" LEDs that light up when plugged into a computer would still light up, but nothing more.

A USB charger puts out 5V unless the device negotiates a higher voltage. That means a standard 5V USB device would power up.

There wouldn't be any "host" USB controller, so the stick would just sit there waiting to be asked what it is and getting no communication. It will not magically become a powered wifi hotspot or a powerline memory stick, nor will either burst into flames.

It would take a small amount of power and that is all.

That's it.

Comment: " A USB charger puts out 5V unless the device negotiates a higher voltage. "  A charger only negotiates a higher voltage if it's "smart charger" using a charging protocol such as USB-PD, Quick Charge, Dash Charge, Warp Charge, or Ludicrous Charge.  (Maybe I made that last one up.)  Calling them a charger is a bit of a misnomer, they are power supplies, the actual charger is most often inside the device.  Some "smart chargers" will not supply power unless there is a request for power from the device.  That's a good answer, I'm just picking at nits.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a "standard" phone charger (5 Volts), nothing should happen to it. But it will not do anything either. So you should be fine.

A wireless adapter may do nothing, or it may (if a cell adapter) start to work. I do that with my HUAWEI stick.